# EVERGREEN string question. Combinations and permutations

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many strings with seven or more characters can be formed from the letters in EVERGREEN if the two R's are consecutive?

I know how to do this if the two R's don't have to be consecutive. Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay ill give for 9 letters procreed in same way for 7 ,8.The total letters are $9$ but we want R to be with other so we consider$R+R=1$ so now we have 8 letters so they can  be arranged in $\frac{(1+7)!}{4!}=1680$ divided by $4!$ as there are identical 'E'.  Total strings of length $7$ are$\frac{7!}{4!}$ but where $R$ is consecutive are $\frac{(1+5)!}{4!}=30$ and fir $8$ total strings are $\frac{8!}{4!}$ but with condition they are $\frac{(1+6)!}{4!}=210$so total ways are $1680+30+210=1920$ . Hope i am clear on this.

Comment: Actually, that only covers the possibility when the word has 9 letters. The question is 7 or more letters

Comment: So its easy i just gave for 9 . You can do for 7,8 by selecting r,r and all e and 1 letter ie $8C7. (1+6)!/4!$ and same manner for 8.

Comment: I didn't get that

Comment: Neglect what i said before.

Answer (score 1):

Treat the two $R$'s as one character.  Say, for example as $R\!\!_R$.

How many ways are there to arrange 7 or more of the letters from $E,E,E,E,G,N,R\!\!_R, V$ if $R\!\!_R$ wasn't one of the choices or 6 or more of them if $R\!\!_R$ was one of the choices.

Comment: Do you think you could do the math for me?

Comment: @satjav You said yourself `I know how to do this if the two R's don't have to be consecutive`.

Comment: Yes but I would like to have a double check, because I still have doubt in my answer, regarding the repeating E's